# Как правильно кириллицей передать Google Maps? Что с прописными и строчными?

Tags: прописная-строчная, латиница-кириллица

> Чтобы не расстраиваться: есть вариант – выбрать хорошую смотровую
>   площадку через гугл мапс, надеть удобные ботинки и прихватить всё для
>   пикника.

Я сама пишу Гугл-Книги, когда ссылаюсь на этот ресурс, то есть через дефис и две с прописной.

Где проверить? Что подсказывает ваш опыт?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если ориентироваться на существующие формальные правила, то в грамматическом смысле можно трактовать интернет-сервисы с иноязычными названиями как *разновидность предприятий*: есть **корпорация "Гугл"** (может употребляться и в латинице - без кавычек: **Google**), и есть её дочерние подразделения. Если наименование предприятия транслитерируется или переводится, то заглавные буквы употребляются в начале и при элементах, являющихся именами собственными. Отсюда варианты **"Гугл книги" ("Гугл букс", Google Books) и "Гугл карты" ("Гугл мэпс", Google Maps)**.

С официального сайта Роспечати:

http://www.fapmc.ru/rospechat/newsandevents/media/2009/11/item8870.html

> Корпорация «Гугл» запустила российскую версию проекта **«Гугл книги»**

"Грамота" о кавычках:
http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/75-kav2

> *... основные семантические группы условных наименований, заключаемых в*
>   *кавычки*
>
> - *названия интернет-ресурсов и веб-сервисов: «Яндекс», «Рамблер», порталы «Грамота.ру», «Культура письменной речи», сайт «Медуза»;
>     социальные сети «Фейсбук», «ВКонтакте». В бытовом употреблении (при
>     передаче на письме разговорной речи) допустимо написание строчными без
>     кавычек: пост в фейсбуке, рекламная ссылка из гугла, фото в
>     инстаграме, забронировал номер на букинге. Написанные латиницей
>     наименования не заключаются в кавычки: портал Delfi, поисковая система
>     Baidu.*

В сомнительных случаях безупречен вариант вставки латиницей. Такой случай намечается в виде официального **Google Карты**:

https://www.google.com/intl/ru_RU/maps/about/

Со стороны американских товарищей несуразица случается часто, например есть целая книга рекомендаций перевода русских сочетаний на американский английский (случайно там есть и *Гугл книги* - без кавычек; есть много грубых ошибок с опечатками), так что, пока сомнительный гибридный вариант не зарегистрирован юридически, в книжке спокойнее всего написать **Google Maps**.

Answer (score 1):

Если это название ресурса, всё же оба слова с прописной.

На картографических сайтах тоже пишут оба слова с большой и раздельно: http://pc4me.ru/gugl-maps.html

Например: *Гугл Мапс сейчас лидирует среди картографических сервисов, которые предоставляют возможность ознакомиться с местностью в режиме онлайн.*

*В области картографических сервисов имеются ещё Яндекс.Карты и Open Street Maps — этот сервис подобен википедии, где любой желающий может внести данные в базу. Но он многократно уступает ресурсу от Google.*

http://rerive.com/google_map_online.html

А вот гугл-книги - не названия книг, а их тип, поэтому корректно было бы оба слова писать со строчной буквы.

Comment: Второе слово ("карты") с заглавной - на основании сетевой практики? "Гугл книги"- не разновидность  книг (ср. "Голос - дети"), это тоже сервис (через 2 кнопки справа) - по поиску книг с просмотром отдельных страниц.