# Как правильно пишется "Гугл" на русском языке?

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфография

Так, как я написала в вопросе, или иначе? В кавычках или без них? С прописной буквы или со строчной?

Comment: Если вам дан хороший ответ, пожалуйста, не забудьте отметить его галочкой.

Comment: Было несколько подобных вопросов (можно поиском посмотреть), вот недавний: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/440573/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-google-maps-%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот что пишет словарь синонимов [**synonymonline.ru**](http://synonymonline.ru/%D0%93/%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB):

**гугл** — существительное, имеет следующие синонимы:
поисковик, интернет, соцсеть, поиск, система, программа, компания.

Вы не привели контекста, по которому было бы видно **что** из вышеперечисленного имется в виду (а от этого, собственно, и зависит форма написания слова).

За двадцать с лишним лет (Гугл начал работу в 1996 году как поисковый механизм для цифровой библиотеки Стэнфорда) слово "гугл" практически стало нарицательным и прочно вошло в язык не только само, но и с новообразованиями, уже зафиксированными в словарях.

Орфографический словарь:
[**гуглить**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C), -лю, -лит *(сниж.*).

Словарь компьютерного сленга (2014):
[**гуглить**](https://comp_slang.academic.ru/65/%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C)
пользоваться поисковой системой Google, искать информацию в интернете с помощью Google.
*А инфы по моему девайсу нагуглить не удаётся.

Сегодня ради интереса решил погуглить свои имя и фамилию.*

**Гугл (Google)** — транснациональная поисковая система, которая является признанным мировым лидером по числу обрабатываемых запросов.

**Google ("Гугл")** — если речь идет о компании.

P. S. А поисковик Вам "откликнется" на любое написание (с прописной-строчной или латиницей-кириллицей, с кавычками или без).